# jQuery .trigger('focus') doesn't actually focus the element

Tags: jquery

```
$('input').eq(0).trigger('focus');
```

When I run it on this page for example, it doesn't focus the first input field. Is it not meant to actually focus the element? I would need something that does that.

The reason I am not using `.focus()` is because I would like to send additional variables to the callback function triggered on `focus` and `.trigger()` is able to do that, while `.focus()` is not.

(I need the behaviour to be different when `input` gets `focus` depending on where the trigger is coming from.)

Comment: Side note, `$($('input')[0])` should be just `$('input').eq(0)`

Comment: For this page, the "focus" call back is assigned to the class instead of the input element itself, that's why it seems not working after you called the trigger function on "input". Try  `$(".js-search-field").trigger('focus');`